# Add event handler dynamically having the delegate name in a string

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-3.5, event-handling

I need to assign an eventHandler to an object, in this way:

```
_Element.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseLeftButtonUpEvent, 
    new RoutedEventHandler(Vars.Digit), true);
```

but, in fact, I only have a string that contains "Digit" or other method name in the Vars object instance.

It is possible to achieve this using reflection or other kind of trick?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can find the method with [`Type.GetMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zz808e6.aspx), and the event with [`Type.GetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wh463yz3.aspx), then add a handler with [`EventInfo.AddEventHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.eventinfo.addeventhandler.aspx). It may be slightly fiddly - and there'll be a lot of places to put error handling - but it shouldn't be too hard. Don't forget to specify binding flags if you want to be able to bind non-public methods/events.

Comment: Thanks, but having the instance of an object(Vars in the snippet), how can I tell to the _Element.AddHandler that point at the method named "Digit" of this specific object? Thanks Again Jon.

Comment: Use `Vars.GetType()` to get the type containing the method you want to add a handler for, and `_Element.GetType()` to find the type containing the event. `AddEventHandler` takes an object which is the "target" of the delegate - in your case this would be `Vars`.