# Attaching an event handler through reflexion

Tags: c#, reflection, event-handling, .net-3.5, c#-3.0

I have the following code:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication
{
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Device device = new Device();
            device.Command += new EventHandler<DeviceSpecialArgs>(device_Command);
        }

        public static void device_Command(Object source, DeviceSpecialArgs args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Command: {0}, Reguest: {1}", args.Command, args.Request);
        }
    }
}
```

I have to do the exact same thing but the assembly containing types Device and DeviceSpecialArgs need to be loaded at runtime. I know how to load the assembly with reflection but I find the event handling part puzzling:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Load the assembly
        string dllPath = @"C:\Temp\Device.dll"
        Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(dllPath);

        // Instanciate Device
        Type deviceType = asm.GetType("Device");
        object device = Activator.CreateInstance(deviceType);

        // How do I subscribe to the Command event?
    }

    // args would normally be a DeviceSpecialArgs but since that type is 
    // unknown at compile time, how do I prototype the handler?
    public static void device_Command(Object source, ??? args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Command: {0}, Reguest: {1}", args.Command, args.Request);
    }   
}
```

How do I subscribe to the event using reflection? Also, how should I prototype the handler itself since the type of "args" is unknown at compile time? FYI, I'm C# 3 and .NET 3.5.

Comment: Look at this post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900302/add-event-handler-dynamically-having-the-delegate-name-in-a-string). Seems to be a duplicate.

Comment: Type safety is enforced here, you must write the event handler with an *e* argument whose type is compatible with the delegate type.  All you got is *object*.  You then also need reflection on e.GetType() to dig out the properties you need.

Answer (score 1):

Firsly, look at the [MAF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384200%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Alternative way is to add to the first assembly a reference to the second one. Then create a couple of interfaces in the second assembly and make the classes in the first one to implement them:

```
public interface IDeviceSpecialArgs
{
    string Command { get; }
    string Request { get; }
}

public interface IDevice
{
    event EventHandler<IDeviceSpecialArgs> Command;
}
```

The first assembly:

```
public sealed class DeviceSpecialArgs : EventArgs, IDeviceSpecialArgs
{
    private readonly string command;
    private readonly string request;

    public string Command
    {
        get { return command; }
    }

    public string Request
    {
        get { return request; }
    }

    public DeviceSpecialArgs(string command, string request)
    {
        this.command = command;
        this.request = request;
    }
}

public class Device : IDevice
{
    public event EventHandler<IDeviceSpecialArgs> Command;

    ...
}
```

In the second assembly simply cast newly instantiated objects to the corresponding interfaces:

```
IDevice device = Activator.CreateInstance(deviceType) as IDevice;
```

Now you can subscribe to the `Command` event, because it is declared in the `IDevice` interface:

```
device.Command += new EventHandler<IDeviceSpecialArgs>(device_Command);
```

**EDIT:** If you have no control over the assembly you are loading, please try the following code. It just creates a handler with the `EventArgs` type of the second argument and uses a reflection to get its properties:

```
internal class DeviceEvent
{
    private readonly Type deviceType;
    private readonly Type deviceSpecialArgsType;

    public DeviceEvent()
    {
        // Load the assembly
        const string dllPath = @"C:\Temp\Device.dll";
        Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(dllPath);

        // Get types
        deviceType = asm.GetType("Device");
        deviceSpecialArgsType = asm.GetType("DeviceSpecialArgs");

        // Instantiate Device
        object device = Activator.CreateInstance(deviceType);
        // Subscribe to the Command event
        deviceType.GetEvent("Command").AddEventHandler(device, (Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(EventHandler), GetType().GetMethod("Device_Command", BindingFlags.NonPublic))));
    }

    private void Device_Command(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string command = deviceSpecialArgsType.GetProperty("Command", BindingFlags.Public).GetValue(e, null).ToString();
        string request = deviceSpecialArgsType.GetProperty("Request", BindingFlags.Public).GetValue(e, null).ToString();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but, unfortunately, I have no control over the assembly I'm loading (it's provided by a third party). Also, adding it as a reference is not possible in this case. Reflection is the only option.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please note, it wasn't tested.